# Facebook Graph Api: Share a link with a specified locale?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, locale

I am trying to automatically share a link with the graph api, but
by specifing a locale so the shared link only appears to for example English users.

Here is the PHP code using Facebook php sdk.

```
try {
    $res = $facebook->api('/' . $PAGEID . '/feed/', 'POST',
    array(
        'access_token' => $pageToken,
        'link' => $url,
        'scrape' => 'true',
        'locale' => 'en_US'
    ));
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
}
```

Here are the meta data in the head of the url i am sharing

```
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Example.com" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Example.com" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/" />
```

I tried to change en_US by en_us.
I also selected a primary language French in the "App Dashboard Localization" and a second language English.

Sharing a link works, but for everyone, the locale is not working... :(

EDIT Resolved : Example for all English locales
The id of locales can be found by querying https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=en&type=adlocale

```
try {
    $res = $facebook->api('/' . $PAGEID . '/feed/', 'POST',
    array(
        'access_token' => $pageToken,
        'link' => $url,
        'targeting' => "{'locales':['6', '51', '24', '1001']}"
    ));
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [post targeting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#targeting), not the locale.

Post targeting allows you to limit posts to the following criteria:

- Age
- Gender
- Relationship Status (“Interested In” in the Advertising create Flow)
- Language
- Education
- College Grad (college name, major year)
- In high school
- Workplace
- Geographic Location
- Country
- State
- City

The down side though is that this functionality is only available to Pages, not user posts, however, there is a trick that can give you the same behaviour, but will cost you some time and effort.

according to [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/), in normal user posts, there is a privacy parameter, that can be customised to exclude users, or only be visible to specific users, what you need to do is:

- Read user's friend list (and filter countries you want), this will require extended perms.
- Feed the filtered list of given friends into the privacy parameter (English speakers, People from Canada, people who like a specific page, etc..)

as I said, it will take more work, but it will get the job done if you really need that feature.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what i needed for my Pages.
How did i miss the targeting parameter :/

Comment: You're welcome, Can't blame you because FB's docs are messy and hard to navigate !